# jQuery multi filter

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I'm working on a website which has some pages like About, Portfolio, Contact, etc. I'd like to add the possibility to have these pages in different languages. Dutch is the default language, the other one is English.
On top of the website there's a menu with clickable links. Each link shows a page. On the top right corner of the website there's a language selector. Clicking on a flag opens the current page in the chosen language.

All pages are div's, like this:

```
<div class="item about nl">content in Dutch</div>
<div class="item about en">content in English</div>`
```

etc...

About is the default page to open, in Dutch. I'm able to filter single pages, but I need help with an extra language filter.
To be clear, when entering the website all pages (div's) are hidden except the About page in Dutch. Clicking a link hides the current page and opens the new page. Clicking a language shows the current page in the chosen language.
I hope someone can help me. Tnx in advance.

Comment: Do you want to select `div`s having two specific classes?

Comment: So you got an ajax page with hidden div's for different sites. Can you post your JS code? And if you think your show/hide is a good way to work (it is okay with small pages!) why don't you do the same with your language files? $(.item.about.en).show(); Of course you have to filter on which "page"/div you are at the moment to get the same just in english..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with javascript, but on the server side based on [`Accept-Language`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). See [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) in Apache for example.

Additionally, you can provide the language links and save the current language preference in a session variable.

When you provide multiple `div`s with content in several languages, you also increase the transmitted page size. This can grow quite large, when you plan to provide a lot of languages.